# Difference between Hypermax and Approximate Deep Maxn

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I do not understand the difference between [Hypermax](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:761634/FULLTEXT01.pdf) and [Approximate Deep Maxn](http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/papers/multiplayergamesthesis.pdf) (ADP, page 87, 98). ADP predates Hypermax by about 10 years.

To me it seems like the very small differences between the two algorithms can be transformed away by modifying the score evaluation function. For example ADP requires an upper bound on the sum of all scores while Hypermax wants zero-sum. An upper bounded sum of scores can be transformed to a 0-sum game for example by applying the transformation described in the Hypermax article: subtract the average score from all scores. If the sum of scores is upper bounded then the average is well defined because you don't divide by infinity.

Is my understanding wrong? Are they the same algorithm under different names?